# add file name without file path to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I am using Blair's Python script which modifies a CSV file to add the filename as the last column (script appended below). However, instead of adding the file name alone, I also get the Path and File name in the last column.

I run the below script in windows 7 `cmd` with the following command:

```
python C:\data\set1\subseta\add_filename.py C:\data\set1\subseta\20100815.csv
```

The resulting ID field is populated by the following `C:\data\set1\subseta\20100815.csv`, although, all I need is `20100815.csv`.

I'm new to python so any suggestion is appreciated!

```
import csv
import sys

def process_file(filename):
    # Read the contents of the file into a list of lines.
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    contents = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    # Use a CSV reader to parse the contents.
    reader = csv.reader(contents)

    # Open the output and create a CSV writer for it.
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # Process the header.
    header = reader.next()
    header.append('ID')
    writer.writerow(header)

    # Process each row of the body.
    for row in reader:
        row.append(filename)
        writer.writerow(row)

    # Close the file and we're done.
    f.close()

# Run the function on all command-line arguments. Note that this does no
# checking for things such as file existence or permissions.
map(process_file, sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: actually worked once I changed working directory to where script is located by using os.chdir()

Answer (score 3):

Use `os.path.basename(filename)`. See http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html for more details.

Comment: Note that if you're testing this on a Unix system, you'll have to remember to use `ntpath` instead (a mistake I just made..)